# delete a file in protected mode env(like windows xp)

Tags: c++, assembly, operating-system, x86-16

I write a program to delete a file from somewhere of my harddisk in 8086
but when i use int 21h (ah=41h) an error happens and carry set to 1.and I cannot delete that.
does anyone know what can I do?
I think it should be from protected mode which does not allow my program to delete another file.I want the answer and language is not matter.

Comment: Why aren't you using the stdio library? Just curious why you are at such a low level for file functions.

Comment: He's writing a virus for a competition, so it's said. See comments on previous questions.

Comment: I happen to be designing some of the security characteristics in an operating system (our own OS). If he knew where to go in memory, he could make a far jump back and enter real mode...but that could be really dangerous if he doesn't know what he's doing. If it is malicious, I hope he does try it on his machine first...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assemble and link your program to as a DOS executable, it should work (provided the code is correct for DOS, of course).

My guess is that you're assembling and linking it to a Windows executable. In that case, you need to use the Windows `DeleteFile` function to delete the file.